# Decrypt GPG file attached in email

Tags: java, encryption, email-attachments, gnupg

I have en email in EML format that contains a PGP attachment.
If I open the email with a text editor the PGP attachment looks like:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; name="038dat123445.pgp"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
MIME-Version: 1.0

begin 600 038dat6420131118154533.pgp
MJ`-01U#!P$X#Z7$!^D<__N<0`_D!_`]+ADPKO>W%VZ.OD_7K@;RA^,%48),3
M^SO6P!II-?LL6=-Z_5XGFBGH+LO*T@Z?LZQRKR#?8?-TF;9A[K4M]N)K!5]K
...
I'SUM0^6=WU=;E82?"<C$!JQU'K!2"7L6=_&"=`$IH<&FD0X>S$0LO5D`
`
end
```

But When I save the PGP attachment and it looks like:

```
ЁPGPБАNйqъG?юзщьK†L+ЅнЕЫЈЇ“хлЃјЎшБT`“ы;ЦАi5ы,YУzэ^'љ)и.
...
CеќЯW[•„џ   ИД¬u°R    {wс‚t)ЎБ¦‘МD,ЅY
```

Note that I can decrypt the code above with PGP.

So, I don't understand how I can convert the text/plain PGP attachment to this binary format.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

well, probably your message is missing part where it should tell it's encoding, like charset="UTF-8"
try to play with encoding